# Model and ordered list in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I need to model a list of items which is sorted by the time of last update of the item.

Consider for instance a user task list. Each user has a list of tasks and each tasks has a due date. Tasks can be added to that list, but also the due date of a task can change after it has been added to the list. 
That is, a task which is in the 3rd position in the task list of User A may have to be moved to the 1st, as a result of the due date of the task being updated.

What I have right now is the following CF:

```
Create Table UserTasks (
    user_id uuid,
    task_id timeuuid,
    new_due_date timestamp
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, task_id));
```

I understand that I cannot sort on 'new_due_date' unless it is made part of the key.
But if its part of the key then it cannot be updated unless but rather deleted and recreated.
My concerns in doing so is that if a task exists in the task list of 100.000 users, then I need to make 100.000 select/delete/insert sequence.
While if I could sort on new_due_date it's be 100.000 updates

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is select/delete/insert really a pain for you since write is fast in Cassandra? maybe you could create a secondary index on timestamp. But I'm not sure it will be better

Comment: may not be a pain, just looking to see if there is an alternative. The problem with secondary index on timestamp is you cannot query ranges. For instance select tasks that due date is > 'xxx'

Answer (score 0):

Well, one option is if use PlayOrm with cassandra, you can partition by user_id and query for UserTasks of a user.  If you query where time > 0 and time < MAX, it returns a cursor(reading in batchSize rows at a time) and you can traverse the cursor in reverse order or just plain order.  This solution scales infinitely with number of users, but only scales to millions of tasks per user which may be ok but I don't know your domain well enough.

Dean